# How to log out after sign in

Tags: python, flask

Im using [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/) Flask code. Its working fine till now, but what if I wanna logout. I would like to have a button on my html code, and when I logout to request auth again.
How can I impliment this code

```
def check_auth(username, password):
    """This function is called to check if a username /
    password combination is valid.
    """
    return username == 'admin' and password == 'secret'

def authenticate():
    """Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth"""
    return Response(
    'Could not verify your access level for that URL.\n'
    'You have to login with proper credentials', 401,
    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

@app.route("/")
@requires_auth
def index():
    return render_template("welcome.html", uptime=GetUptime())
#Logout function
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    #return redirect(url_for('index'))
    flash('You were logged out')
    return authenticate()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Basic auth. It doesn't have the concept of "log out", but, you can simulate one by sending wrong credentials (for instance a username with an invalid password) and returning `401` instead of `200`. There are multiple ways to implement a logout, but for keeping it simple you could render a template view or return an informative text, always using `401` as the response http code:

```
@ns.route('/logout')
def logout():
    """End the current user session"""
    return "Your session was closed", 401
```

Comment: Hey snahor! I updated the first post with a logout button. I'm able to force the user with this function to auth his self again. The problem with this is: A pop up window is poping on the sceen asking for user and pass, but on the background the user is still able to click buttons etc. How is possible to redirect first the user to the index page were no buttons exist and then ask for user and pass again. I added the line return redirect(url_for('index')) but after the redirection it does not force the user to login again. In other words, return authenticate() is skipped.

Comment: Your `logout` function ends with the redirect hence there's no 401. `logout` should call `authenticate` only, you don't need neither flash nor redirect. If you want to redirect to the index after logout, you must do it with javascript and redirect when you receive a 401 status.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a session with the auth data (no matter whether use basic auth), and when you want log out simply delete the session data.

Answer (score 0):

If your using the nice flask-login extension you can use the logout_user function

```
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user
```

Then just create an endpoint (url) for it

```
@expose('/logout/')
def logout(self):
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index')
```